# qual comando SQL exibiria os registros onde o campo LastName seja "Duck" e a data no campo BirthDate seja maior que 01/01/1950?

Tags: mysql

Considerando a tabela, qual comando SQL exibiria os registros onde o campo LastName seja "Duck" e a data no campo BirthDate seja maior que 01/01/1950?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá *user*, você tem um SGBD específico em mente ou essa é uma questão teórica? (Se você tem um SGDB específico em mente edite sua questão acrescentando uma *tag*).

Comment: Já editei. É MySQL.

Comment: @Stell não se esqueça de ver o [tour] para entender o mecanismo do site. Você pode votar nas respostas que lhe ajudaram de alguma forma e aceitar a resposta que foi a melhor em cada pergunta que fez.

Answer (score 5):

Supondo que o nome da tabela em questão seja "myTable":

```
select
  *
from mytable
where lastname = 'Duck'
  and birthdate > '1950.01.01'
```

Comando testado no MySQL 5.5.

Obs.: Sempre que possível, recomendo formate o comando. Para comandos extensos esse costume é essencial para evitar construções erradas e facilitar manutenções.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LastName = 'Duck' AND BirthDate > DATE('1950-01-01');
```

Onde table é o nome da tabela. Veja que o `*` irá mostrar todos os campos, caso queira algo específico, substitua `*` pelo nome do campo desejado.
Note que o formato da data no comando deve ser igual ao formato do campo BirthDate.