# Comando SQL para exibir registros específicos do campo "id"

Tags: mysql, sql

Qual comando SQL exibiria os registros onde o campo `id` fosse 22, 23, 25 e 27?

[image: exemplo de resultado]

Answer (score 22):

Seria algo como:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id IN (22,23,25,27);
```

**O Operador IN:**

O operador `IN` permite que você especifique vários valores em uma cláusula `WHERE`.

**Sintaxe:**

```
SELECT column_name(s)
 FROM table_name
 WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...);
```

Também funciona com strings:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
 WHERE City IN ('Paris','London');
```

Fonte: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Comment: O IN é mais "limpo" ...

Answer (score 5):

Basicamente o mesmo da [sua pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30896/101). Só que agora usa o OR para selecionar mais do que um, ou seja 22 OU 23 OU 25 OU 27, qualquer um deles será selecionado.

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = 22 OR id = 23 OR id = 25 OR id = 27;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/WhereOr.sql).

Comment: Por que não usar AND?

Comment: `AND` significa `E`, certo? Então quando você usa o AND, você quer que ambas as condições sejam verdadeiras. Se trocasse o `OR` por `AND` neste ´SELECT`, não retornaria nada. Porque qual linha teria o is 22 E 23 E 35 E 27. Nenhum! Para isto cada linha teria que ter mais de um `id` e pelo modelo mostrado isto é impossível. Podemos interpretar o `AND` como excludente, enquanto que o `OR` é inclusivo, é somador, ele adiciona tudo o que se encaixa nas condições.

Comment: Pq com and o id teria de ser igual a 22 e 23 e ... , impossível.

Comment: E quanto a usar IN(22,23,25,27);?

Comment: Também funciona, eu preferi usar esta forma que é mais básica porque entendi que você está iniciando e precisa entender a diferença entre `AND` e `OR`. No caso do `IN` você está dizendo "quero que seja qualquer linha que esteja DENTRO desta faixa de valores. Na prática dá o mesmo resultado". Quando você ficar mais experiente vai sempre preferir usar o `IN` **neste** caso de ser uma lista de dados. Em outros casos, só o `OR` vai resolver.

Comment: Será que m algo errado aqui para ter negativo?

Comment: `IN(1,2,3,n...)` é esteticamente mais bonito e mais simples de digitar, mas dá no mesmo de id = 1 or id=2 or id=3...

Comment: Você também pode fazer isso: `...where id IN(1,2,3) or id IN (4,5,6)` e também pode negar: `...where id NOT IN(1,2,3)`

Comment: E se quiser ordenar por unidade, faça algo assim: `... order by FIELD(id, 22,23,25,27)`

Answer (score 0):

melhor forma! vai selecionar os campos como quer

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = 22 and id REGEXP '(23|25|27)';
```